# Logic circuit with not gate-stability

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdubix.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why is the first circuit unstable and the second one stable?

Comment: Have you tried to understand it? Try to assign a logical value to a node in either circuit, and work it from there.

Comment: I agree with Clabacchio, you can immediately see what happens when you follow the sequence of events from a starting logic value and what happens afterwards

Comment: I personally wouldn't call the first circuit unstable, I'd call it a semi-stable oscillator. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to go through these circuits. Lets say that on the left side of the first inverter is a logic value of 1. This value is inverted and is 0 at the left side of the second inverter. This will become a value of 1 on the left side of the 3rd inverter. After the 3rd inverter the value is 0. this value is also on the left side of the first inverter. Where it was 1 in the beginning it is now 0. So that circuit toggles the input all the time making it unstable.

At the circuit on the right:
left say we have a logic value of 1 again on the left side of the first inverter. this value will be inverted to a value of 0. Then the 0 will be inverted again which will make a 1 on the left side of the first inverter. We started with a logic value of 1 and we end with a logic value of 1. That makes this circuit stable.

Comment: I dont understand what does alternate low and high voltages being provided as inputs to the first gate make it unstable. why is this case called "unstabe". What ill effect the circuit will undergo?

Comment: A stable circuit is a circuit that will get a constant value over a certain time. Even if that is after 5 minutes the circuit is still 'stable'. With the circuit on the left with the 3 inverters we found out that when you start with a logic value of 1 you will get a logic value of 0. Now if you put the logic value of 0 in at the left of the first inverter you will get eventually after all 3 inverters a logic value of 1. this goes on and on so you will get some thing like this: 1-0-1-0-1-0-1-0-1.. etc. As you can see this circuit doesn't have a constant value after a certain amount time.

Answer (score 2):

Gate delay causes it to ripple. While the first one is receiving the output of the last one, the middle one is propagating the output of the first one, and it will continue like this forever.

The logic in general will cause this toggling, because it would go 1:0:1, or 0:1:0 and would constantly oscillate between these states.